How can I load an ARMv8 based kernel into Qemu using a given fsbl and ssbl?
From what I have read, I know that using the -kernel option is geared toward emulating Linux kernel based software unless the file passed into that option is an ARM elf file. I have a custom aarch64 ARMv8 kernel that I would like to spin up, but I just can't find enough documentation to get me there.
I also have the first and second stage bootloaders, but I'm not sure how to leverage them to boot my main kernel.
I am also lost on what my dtb would look like. I've read that I need to provide one since I will be using a virt board with virtualization turned on.
I would appreciate some help in contextualizing these different elements in order to get a working emulation of the device.
I wish I could provide code here, but I don't think I can. I am really just looking for a command line and dtb that I can start with.
Would something like this be right?
qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -kernel my_kernel -dtb my_dtb.dtb -drive file=first_stage.img,format=raw,if=none -device virtio-blk-device,drive=first_stage -drive file=second_stage.img,format=raw,if=none -device virtio-blk-device,drive=second_stage
Or would I use pflash for the bootloaders? I don't think they are exactly 32 MB as the spec calls for.

Update: I think this might be a more accurate command line? I'm not super sure if I will be able to tell if it is working though...
qemu-system-aarch64 -smp 4 -m 2G -machine virt -display none -serial stdio -kernel my_kernel -bios my_fsbl.bin -device loader,file=my_ssbl.bin

The "virt" board is the one QEMU board where you do not need to provide your own dtb -- QEMU will create one internally and provide it to the guest software.

I see. I figured I would need it since I am using custom bootloaders. Are the other options I have listed correct in your view?

It depends on how "my_kernel" expects to run and how it wants to load the "first_stage" and "second_stage" files. But probably it will be easier to load those files into guest RAM with the "generic loader" rather than putting them on block devices and requiring the my_kernel to do load-from-disk of them. NB: you say "first and second stage bootloaders that the software shipped with" -- unless these were written to work with the QEMU 'virt' board chances are very unlikely that they will run successfully.

Thanks for the response. So why would the virt board not work for this? Is that because the bootloaders are compiled for specific hardware? I also updated my question with a different command line that might be a little more accurate?

It's the specific-hardware problem -- bootloaders and similar system software are built for a specific board type and will just crash when things aren't where they expect. Some bits of system software (like Linux) are able to accept a dtb to tell them about the hardware they're running on, but this is the exception, not the norm.

I see. So, assuming I identify the board and cpu model (which I think I can based on strings), are there any pitfalls to getting these components started up from there? For example, if I start it the emulation, in what way would you recommend to monitor to ensure the boot process is going smoothly? I feel like so much can go wrong during this process and I fear that I won't be able to discern if my issue stems from Qemu options or unforeseen consequences.

My impression is that what you're trying to do is "take some binary blobs that run on a random real piece of hardware, and run them under QEMU". This is somewhere between "difficult" and "impossible" depending on the blobs (and whether you want to try to add emulation of whatever the hardware is to QEMU), and definitely not for the faint-of-heart...

Your impression is correct. I may just have to give up for now. I had just assumed I could plug in a set of binaries into Qemu and expect them to interact with the emulated environment as if they were on the actual hardware. I'm realizing that this isn't realistic now. Thanks again for your responses.

Sometimes you can do that, but the emulated environment has to closely match the actual hardware -- "just same CPU type" isn't close enough.
